# WPF app in Program File(x86) cant create/modify xml/xaml files successfully

Tags: c#

In my WPF application (say MyApp), I have an option where I need to create/modify XML and XAML files. The app is installed in Program Files(x86)\MyAppFolder and location of these xaml/xml files is in a subfolder named "Config" within MyAppFolder. So whenever I try to create or modify xml/xaml files using MyApp and relaunch the MyApp next time I get prompted with the windows installer with a message "Please wait while windows configures MyApp". Windows installer runs and overwrites my changes back to original. When I installed the application I selected "Everyone" option to install it for all the users. The app is available to all the users but works for the user whom we installed from.

This C#/WPF application requires .NET 4 and I am running Windows 7 home premium.

I am creating the installer using the Setup Project type from the Visual Studio 2010 as follows:-

New Project -> Other Project Types -> Setup and Deployment -> Visual Studio Installer -> Setup Project

Comment: You cannot write to Program Files.

Answer (score 1):

As of Windows Vista programs do not run as administrator by default. Only programs that are run as administrator can write to program files. You need to write your config files to CommonApplicationData instead.

```
var commonAppData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)
var configFolder = Path.Compbine(commonAppData, "MyAppFolder")
```

On Windows Vista and up `configFolder` will likely equal `C:\ProgramData\MyAppFolder`.

Comment: I tried a sample based on what you said, and looks like it worked. Thanks for the help. :)